# Will the spacing between the mirror segments of the Webb space telescope degrade the sharpness of its images?

Tags: optics, astronomy, material-science, telescopes, infrared-radiation

I've noticed that the existing spacing between the 18 mirror segments of the Webb space telescope are many times the operational infrared spectrum wavelengths (i.e. 0.6-28μm) of the telescope meaning it will redirect light into wrong hexagonal paths and there will be also probably strong [edge diffraction](https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/presentations/edge-diffraction) of light in the spacings that will possible degrade the sharpness of the telescope and create many artifacts in the obtained images?

[image: Webb mirror segments]

How these problems are addressed in the Webb space telescope? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I am sure the data is interpolated during post processing to edit out the spaces. Our brain does the same thing with our eyes.  Without the post processing, no doubt you are correct.

Comment: @RC_23 I'm not sure that wiping out the artifacts will rectify any sharpness degradation caused. Maybe an other, physical solution or method is used?

Comment: Elements are much larger than the wavelength so no major edge diffraction. Missing area is just less signal relative to one solid mirror. There are many segmented mirrors in use successfully.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/bitstream/handle/2014/9785/02-1931.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: Here’s a video that you may find helpful. https://youtu.be/gOpbXBppUEU

Answer (score 3):

The cracks are far from the image plane, so they are not in focus, and they simply diminish the amount of light collected by the mirror as a whole. It’s sort of like a speck of dust or thin crack in a pair of glasses; you don’t even notice it when your eyes are focused at a far distance.

Comment: Edge diffraction distortions can propagate a good amount towards the center of each mirror contributing blurriness and reducing the effective useful surface of each mirror segment. But yes I understand your given answer that a possible solution to this would be to eliminate by software a portion of mirror surface around the edges. Do we have any reference that this is the actual solution  path chosen from the Webb telescope designers?

Answer (score 3):

Segmented mirrors are quite common, especially if you need to build a very big mirror, otherwise, the mirror can collapse under its own weight. Plus the ease of transport.

Going back to the question: not much.

I'll cite one article on the topic:

> In any case these results suggest that diffraction effects from intersegment gaps should cause few problems
> except perhaps for extreme narrowband imaging.
> (Mitchell Troy and Gary Chanan, "Diffraction effects from giant segmented-mirror telescopes," Appl. Opt. 42, 3745-3753 (2003))

On top of that most of the problems are caused by the obscuration due to the secondary mirror.